# React Native: issue calling imported async functions from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having issues calling my geolocationApi method from my react native components, my file is not a hook (I don't want to use hooks), this is how I call this method:

App.js

```
import  geolocationApi  from '@utils/geolocationApi';

const handleUpdateLocation = async () =>
    {
        try
        {
const root = useMobxStore();            
const result = await geolocationApi(root,true).requestLocationPermissions();
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            throw error;
        }
    };
```

Right now what happens is the function returns automatically and result is undefined, eventhough I'm awaiting the function, it returns automatically.

And if I add async to geolocationApi function, like this:

```
const geolocationApi = async (root, getCityName = false) => { /** **/}
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: (0, _geolocationApi.default)(root, true).requestLocationPermissions is not a function
```

And my geolocationApi file

geolocationApi.js

```
import { AsyncStorage ,Platform, Alert, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';
import env from '@env/vars';
import http from '@env/axiosin';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';



    
const geolocationApi = (root, getCityName = false) => {
        

    const requestLocationPermissions = async () =>
    {
        try{
        let granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) 
            {
                root.mapStore.setLocationEnabled(true);
                
                let results = await getGeolocationCoords();
                //returns { currentCoordinates, newCity }
                return results;
            }
            else
            {
                root.mapStore.setLocationEnabled(false);
            }

    } 
    catch (error)
    {
        throw error;
    }
    };


    const getGeolocationCoords = async () =>
    {
        if (hasLocationPermission) {
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                async (position) => 
                {
                    let coords = position.coords;
                    let newCity = false;
                    let currentCoordinates = { lat:coords.latitude, lng:coords.longitude };
                            
                    return { currentCoordinates, newCity };
                },
                (error) => {
                  console.log(error.code, error.message);
                },
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
            );
    }};

    
    };


    const  hasLocationPermission = async () =>
    {
        return true;        
    };

      //Apparently, this is neccesary to be able to invoke geolocationApi from any component
      return { requestLocationPermissions };
    };
    
    export default geolocationApi;
```

Comment: The reason this is occurring is that you have your functional component (geolocationApi) which cannot be async (top level components cannot be async in react native). Furthermore, the reason you cannot import the function requestLocationPermissions in your other file is because you define it locally in geolocationApi and do not export it. If you want to use requestLocationPermissions in another file, either declare it outside of the body of your functional component and export it or declare it a new file (like a helper file) and export it there.

Comment: The issue is requestLocationPermissiosn invokes other functions inside my geolocationApi